# Angular forcing checkbox checked state

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently upgrading our app version of angular js from 1.0.8 to the latest stable release and running into an interesting issue.

We have a set of checkboxes used to filter information, in general the options are:

- All
- Filter 1
- Filter 2
- Filter N

The desire is to have the 'All' checkbox when clicked, remain checked.  It will do additional logic to determine if the other checkboxes are checked and toggle their checked states off if they are.  I was able to accomplish this with 1.0.8, but not with the latest version of angular.

At its most basic of setup, we just have a single checkbox, with a ng-model value set to some boolean scope variable and a ng-click defined to some function.

I have a plunker demo where one can toggle between 1.0.8 and 1.2.18 to illustrate the change, here: http://plnkr.co/edit/WaTj6e33x4SZ2NkKStsC?p=info

HTML:

```
<body ng-app='example' ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <button type="button" ng-click="toggleCb(true)">All Checked</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="toggleCb(false)">All Unchecked</button>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="allCheckbox" ng-click="toggleCb(true)" id="all"/>
      <label for="all">All</label>
    </div>
    <div>Imagine more checkbox options</div>

    <div>
      <p>Value for checkbox is: {{ allCheckbox }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('example', [])
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.allCheckbox = true;

  $scope.toggleCb = function(value) {
    console.log('called with value', value);
    $scope.allCheckbox = value;
  }
});
```

So this basic example setup has a couple of buttons which when clicked will change the boolean value of the scope variable.  That is to illustrate that setting the scope variable is being respected by the input.  The input is click-bound as well to the same function and when using 1.0.8 it keeps the checkbox checked.

Has anyone had a need to do this with running the latest version of angular, and if so how have you overcome this issue?

Comment: Your Plunker works with both versions. What is the exact problem? What's the desired output?

Comment: @DianaNassar: The desired result: Clicking on the 'All' checkbox itself, not the toggle buttons, will keep the checkbox checked.

Comment: As an alternative solution to this, I suppose I could just disable the 'All' checkbox whenever it's checked, in order to maintain its value and most likely remove confusion to users that they could have no checkboxes checked within my filter list.